# GTK Advice - Link Scale With Progress Bar

Tags: gtk

I'm just beginning with GTK and am looking for some advice. I have a GtkScale which has a range of 0 - 6. I have a progress bar next to it that I would like to have move with the progress bar, i.e. when scale is set to 3, progress bar is set to 50%. What is the best way to link them together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the `GtkScale` widget's [`value-change` signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRange.html#GtkRange-value-changed). In the handler, call [`gtk_range_get_value`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-get-value) to obtain the current value of the scale, and call [`gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkProgressBar.html#gtk-progress-bar-set-fraction) to adjust the progress bar to that value.